# Как привязать БД из MySQL в django?

Tags: python, mysql, django

В settings.py прописано:

```
DATABASES = {
    "default": {

        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'name',
        'USER': 'user',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

При запуске сервера (python manage.py runserver) создается файл c расширением sqlite, где потом и хранится БД. Как привязать БД из MySQL (БД создана)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проверьте, не переопределяется ли дальше в файле настроек DATABASES и тот ли файл настроек вы редактируете, потому что то, что вы написали, должно работать, а у вас явно где-то завалялись строки вроде этих:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

Comment: Можно сделать 

```
$ manage.py shell
>>> from django.conf import settings
>>> print settings.DATABASES
```

и проверить вывод